# Удаления и добавления елементов jquery (button, li)

Tags: javascript, jquery

Мне нужно при нажатии на "удалить", удалять елемент `li` вместе с кнопкой `delete` и `edit`, но ничего не выходит.

```js
var counter = 0;
$("#myb").click(function() {
  alert("ee");
  var text = $("#myp").val();

  $("#myid").append("<p><li  id='" + counter + "'>" + text + "   " + "<button type='button'  id='delete_" + counter + "'>" + "delete" + "</button>" + "   " + "<button type='button' id='edit_" + counter + "'>" + "edit" + "</button>" + "</li></p>");
  $("#myp").val(" ");
  counter++;


  $("#delete_0").click(function() {
    ("li").remove();
  })
  $("#ed").append("<input heidth='50px' wigth= '50px' type='text' id='re'/>");

  $("#edit_0").click(function() {
    var s = $("#0").innerText();
    $("#ed").apppend("<p> " + s + "</p>")

  })
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p id="myid"> </p>
<input type="text" id="myp" />
<button type="button" id="myb">Add</button>

<center>
  <p id="ed"> </p>
</center>
```

Comment: вам бы с опечатками разобраться сначала

Comment: Есть небольшое подозрение, что код писался закрытыми глазами. Где `ul`? Почему `counter` считает, а навешивает обработчик на `_0`? Зачем добавлять `input`? Почему `id` начинается и состоит из цифры? Почему... Ладно, вы поняли.

Comment: Извините, я только учюсь. Спасибо за то, что указали на ошибки.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
let ulEl = $('ul');
$('#addNewItemBtn').on('click', function(e){ // Слушаем кнопку добавления
  let item = $('#newItem');
  let text = item.val().trim();
  
  if(text.length) { // Если есть текст - добавляем
    ulEl.append(`<li><span>${text}</span> <input type='button' class='removeBtn' value='Remove' /></li>`);
    item.val('');
  }
});

ulEl.on('click', '.removeBtn', function(e){ // Слушаем нажатие на кнопку удаления
  $(this).parent('li').remove(); // Ищем предка li (у каждой кнопки он свой) и удаляем его
});
```

```css
ul {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0; padding: 0;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<ul></ul>
<input type='text' id='newItem' />
<input type='button' id='addNewItemBtn' value='Add' />
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
var counter = 0;
$("#myb").click(function(){
  var text=$("#myp").val();
  var cC = counter++;

  $("#myid").append("<p><li  id='"+cC+"'>"+text+"   " +"<button type='button'  id='delete_"+cC+"'>"+ "delete"+"</button>"+"   " +"<button type='button' id='edit_"+cC+"'>"+ "edit"+"</button>" +"</li></p>");
  $("#myp").val(" ");


  $("#delete_"+cC).click(function (){
    $("#"+cC).remove();
  })
  $("#ed").append("<input heidth='50px' wigth= '50px' type='text' id='re'/>");

  $("#edit_"+cC).click(function (){
      var s=$("#0").innerText();
    $("#ed").apppend("<p> "+s+"</p>")

  })
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p id="myid"> </p>
<input type="text" id="myp"/>
<button type="button" id="myb">Add</button>

<center> <p id="ed"> </p></center>
```